# does a windows 8.1 tablet require an antivirus/antispyware program?

Tags: windows-8, anti-virus, windows-tabletpc

I am helping a friend with setting up a Dell Venue 8 tablet. It has Windows 8.1. My friend seems to think that it requires antivirus protection.

I honestly did not know the answer to this. I thought the security model for tablets is a little better than PC OS, but I wasn't sure.

I know that the tablet's default browser is IE, so that sends shivers up my spine from a security-standpoint.

Assuming that most of the apps you use come mainly from the app store, would it be necessary to still buy an antivirus utility? is any antivirus fine, or are there tablet-specific security suites? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dell Venue 8 pro is a normal x86 device so you can install any AV suite you want although it comes with Windows Defender, which replaces [Microsoft Security Essentials (MSE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Security_Essentials) under Windows 8. I personally use [Avast Free](http://www.avast.com/index) on my Toshiba Encore Tablet because Defender is extremely slow and I had issues with updating the virus signatures.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do, however Avast is enough. In fact, you're not supposed to install desktop programs at all.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on which Surface tablet you own because Surface 2/RT runs a different version of Windows than Surface Pro/Pro 2/Pro 3.
Surface 2/RT is very smooth and lighter defender work very well for 2/RT surface so it does not require any additional protection software. But surface 8 pro designs for both device and laptop, in this case defender only able to provide your system minimal protection so it’s better to install any lightweight third party antivirus like Immunet and Avira software in your windows tablet.

Comment: Why are you talking about Windows RT when the question was about Windows 8.1?